# .NET Application is targeting 4.5, Setup.exe says it requires version 2.0.50727

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm working on upgrading a windows application/service to target newer .NET frameworks for a client. This is the first time I've done anything of the sort. I changed the Target Framework in the C# project's properties window to 4.5, rebuilt the project without any errors, and then tried to run setup.exe. When I run this, it says:

```
This setup requires the .NET Framework version 2.0.50727.
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening? I read about launch conditions and that it could possibly be checking that the client computer requires v2.0, but I don't see an option to view the launch conditions in Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/166037

Comment: I don't have version 2 of the framework and I don't want it! I want it to run on v4/4.5

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/166043

Comment: My guess is that while your application requires 4.5, the installer itself uses .NET Framework 2.0 components to accomplish installation.

Comment: @vcsjones how do I go about changing the installer requirements?

Comment: It would help if we knew what sort of installer you are using, and what version it is.

Comment: All I'm doing is double clicking the setup.exe file that is located in my project folder and that is when I run into the error mentioned above.